# Where to find a discrete transmission gate

Tags: components

I have a project where I need to switch analog signals. Ideally, I would like to just use a few transmission gates to do this, but I cannot find ***anyone*** who sells or produces them! I've checked Digi-Key, Allied Elec, and Mouser, but nothing.

Can someone answer the following:

1. Why is a standard component so hard to find?  Am I using the wrong words?
2. If I am using the wrong words, what are the right ones?
3. Can someone recommend a specific part or family of parts for me to check out? (Looking for individual gates in SOT-23 or maybe 4 - 8 in TSSOP or QFN.)

Sorry if this violates the "no shopping or buying recommendations" rule, but I'm not looking for a recommendation, I'm looking for verification of existence!

Comment: "Bilateral switch" seems to be the term that is most often used in the datasheets, such as the CD4016 and CD4066 quad bilateral switches.

Comment: The [Maxim DS3690 datasheet](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS3690T+-DS3690T+TRL.pdf) uses the term "Transmission Gate" but I don't think it's a common description.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes!  Thank you!  "Bilateral switch" is exactly what I was looking for!  Please put up an answer so I can accept it.  I still want to know, though, why is it that the term "transmission gate" returns absolutely nothing?  there is a standard schematic signal for "transmission gates", so I thought that term would be ubiquitous.

Comment: @JYelton  That does look like what I'm looking for... but I'm looking for a net of about 6, not 26 :)

Comment: See also CD4051 and CD405x stablemates.

Comment: Search for analog switch, (as others said) or solid state relay (SSR) for more power. (but slower turn on/off time.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Analog switch` is the term Maxim uses, along with lots of other manufacturers.

By the way, the two hardest parts about this type of application are:

1. high voltage withstand
2. off resistance at high frequency (i.e. pass-through capacitance)

With the part "off", a sufficiently high frequency signal will couple from the input pin to the output pin, without even going through the switch -- energy always wants to take the path of least impedance.

Transmission Gate is a much simpler structure that is found only inside an IC, I don't think it's offered discretely because of the ESD/latchup structures inherent in getting a signal out of an IC.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the in-depth answer about why transmission gates may not be offered in discrete packages.  I remember reading about latchup problems with older SSD analog switches, so it makes sense that they would not be offered discretely.  As far as your points 1 and 2 go, this application is for audio, so the voltage is in the hundreds of millivolts regime and the frequency is always less than about 20kHz.

Answer (score 1):

"Bilateral switch" seems to be the term that is most often used in the datasheets, such as those for the CD4016 and CD4066 quad bilateral switches.

Answer (score 1):

You may prefer to use xx4051/4052/4052 or the less common xx4316 in that they have built-in level translation to allow use of logic level inputs with bipolar supplies.

There are higher performance analog switches that have lower on resistance, protection, level shifting, guaranteed low leakage and so on, but the price gets higher.

Comment: I will be switching audio signals, so I'm not really interested in level translation.  Thank you, though.  I will keep xx4051 and friends in my "cache" in case I need something like that.

Comment: @johnny_boy the level translation is so the device can drive larger voltage swings and have it controlled by a lower voltage signal.

Comment: @johnny_boy Audio will generally use +/- supplies. If you have logic that is the correct level (say -5V for off and +5V for on) then you don't need level translation. But microcontrollers don't generally have outputs that do that, so some extra parts are required. No big deal, but it adds complexity.